# WPF hide row in datatable or in datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable, row, hide

I created datatable and fill it with columns and rows then i "add" this datatable to datagrid and my question is:
How to hide one row? In datatable or datagrid it doesnt matter for me. Its possible to do that?

In Windows Forms was something like CurrencyManager and that do all the job.

Comment: Try binding your DataGrid to a collection and removing the item from the collection which you're looking to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a wayto hide rows:

```
          for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
          {
              DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator
                                                         .ContainerFromIndex(i);
              Console.WriteLine(row.GetIndex());
             // Console.WriteLine(row.Item);

            Console.WriteLine((row.Item as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[3].ToString());
              string plec = (row.Item as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[3].ToString();
              if (plec == "M")
              {
                  row.Focus();
                  row.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
              }
          }
```

But when rows are Collapsed after click on column header to asceding or descending my datagrid show all rows(collapsed rows too).
How to block this and use filter only on visble rows?